# image segmentation using graph cut with seed points

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graph-theory, image-segmentation, max-flow

I'm working in medical image segmentation and I want to combine fuzzy connectedness algorithm with the graph cut, the idea is to segment the image with fuzzy connectedness the background and the foreground will be used as sink and source for the graph cut algorithm, this is my code to obtain the seeds coordinates for the graph cut segmentation

```
FC=afc(S,K); %// Absolute FC
u=FC>thresh;
v=FC<thresh;

s=regionprops(u, 'PixelIdxList'); %// listes de pixels de l´objet
t=regionprops(v, 'PixelIdxList'); %// listes de pixels de l´arrière plan
[a,b]=size(s);
[w,c,z]= size(t)

for i=1:a
    for j=1:b
        [y,x] = ind2sub(size(u), s(i,j).PixelIdxList);
    end
end
for k=1:w
    for d=1:c
        [y1,x1] = ind2sub(size(v), t(k,d).PixelIdxList);
    end
end
```

For the graph cut, I used an algorithm from the [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34126-fast-continuous-max-flow-algorithm-to-2d-3d-image-segmentation/content/CMF%20v1.0/CMF_Cut.m)

For example, I can define

```
Cs=-log([y x])
Ct=-log([y1 x1])
```

but the problem is how to combine the information from the cost functions like this part of the code source

```
u = double((Cs-Ct) >= 0);
ps = min(Cs, Ct);
pt = ps
```

it will exceed the matrix size

Answer (score 6):

I am not familiar with the graph-cut implementation from FEX you linked to,
but I'll show an example using [`GCMex` matlab wrapper](https://github.com/shaibagon/GCMex) (proper disclosure: I implemented this wrapper).

Assuming you have an image of size `size(S)` with `n` pixels and `K` a **sparse** matrix of size `n`-by-`n` with `K(ii,jj)` representing how well `ii` and `jj` pixels are connected (for neighboring `ii` and `jj`).
Moreover, you have a mask `u` of foreground pixels and a mask `v` of background pixels to be treated as hard constraints.

First, construct the data term using `u` and `v`:

```
Dc = 1000*[u(:), v(:)]; %// assign very large cost for picking FG pixel to label zero and vice versa
```

As you can see the data-term `Dc`, is `n`-by-2 array with the cost of assigning label `l` (either 0 or one) to pixel `ii` is stored in `Dc(ii,l+1)`. Therefore, for pixels in the foreground (`u(ii)` is 1) assigning label `l=0` (i.e. background) the cost you pay is 1000. The same goes for pixels in the background (`v(ii)` is 1) assigning them to foreground (i.e., `l`=1) is cost 1000. Therefore, the data term `Dc` gives very high cost to seed pixels (either foreground or background) getting the wrong label.

Construct a graph-cut object

```
gch = GraphCut('open'), Dc, [0 1; 1 0], K );
[gch L] = GraphCut('expand',gch);
gch = GraphCut('close',gch);
L = reshape(L, size(u)); 
figure; imshow(L,[]); title('the resulting mask');
```

---

Note that in rder to use [`GCMex`](https://github.com/shaibagon/GCMex) you need to follw the installation instructions and compile it for it to work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, how to distribute the weights to source and Sink? currently the subtract the value of source from maxValue to get the value of sink, does this makes sense.

Comment: follow this  link it's a simple implmentation of interactive graph cut 
https://masterravi.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/interactive-segmentation-using-graph-cutsmatlab-code/

Comment: nice! I am wondering how you would do this interactively, i.e. the user can mark seed pixels as hard constraints also after graph cut has been run before. Is it possible to incorporate this input without recalculating everything?

Comment: @user1809923 you can read more about interactive and iterative image segmentation at [this book chapter](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/147408/RotherEtAlMRFBook-GrabCut.pdf). it presents a very interesting approach to understanding "user intent" in marking seeds and segmentation cues.

Comment: thanks for the link! I have read parts of it by now. However, my question was more related to your Matlab wrapper specifically (or for another matlab implementation for that matter).

Comment: @user1809923 my wrapper is quite limited. It offers a global solution thus it needs to re-calculate after every addition of seeds. It might be possible to dive into the wrapped C++ code to re-use graph paths across calculations in order to make the refinement iterations more efficient. But this type of optimization is beyond the scope of this wrapper.